# data model for user register system with blacklist and favoritelist?

Tags: mysql, database-design

can someone show me data model for user register system which user can favorite or blacklist(ban) each other?i am looking for best way but no one answered my questions well until now.by best way i mean we have less join for programing.

my user table until now

```
uid(pk) | name | family | blah blah blah ..
```

i just dont know how to desgin this favorite and blacklist which we just have one join or less?

i think it must be a one to many relation but how should i design this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could have a second table listing the blacklists and/or favourites

table
id(pk) | userid_src(fk) | userid_dst(fk) | type

If user A blacklists user B and then user A favourites user C and user B and C favourites each other you will have this where A is id 1, B id 2 and C id 3

```
id(pk) | userid_src(fk) | userid_dst(fk) | type
1      | 1              | 2              | blacklist
2      | 1              | 3              | favourite
3      | 2              | 3              | favourite
4      | 3              | 2              | favourite
```

EDIT: to retrieve the info of each user :

```
SELECT * from users
LEFT JOIN users_connections as con ON users.uid = con.userid_src
LEFT JOIN users as userCon ON userCon.uid = con.userid_dst
WHERE users.id = XXX
```

XXX will be the id of your current user. You will then retrieve each connections between your current user and each user he blacklisted or added as favourite.

Comment: is id(pk) auto increment if i am right?then if we have 10 melyon of user and each user have 200 person in black list and favorite list then we have this id 2000 melyon of row or more is this ok?

Comment: I don't know if it's ok that will depend on your database, your server hardware/configuration, but yeah.
You could otherwise create a table for each user's "lists" storing favourite/blacklists in it but then you'd have millions of table in the end.

Comment: then after creating this we join usertable with this table on userid_src(fk) and we fetch userid_dst(fk) and after that we have to select each user info and this will cause us many query just for fetch info from each user

Comment: I don't see how you could avoid it in the end. And you can perform one unique query with this schema anyway by joining multiple times on the users table

Comment: i think if i have some info from user in this table which you mentioned i wont need to join tables at all can i do this?for example name and family of the user which we banned

Comment: You could but that would mean repeating the same info every time it would be a bit too much since you already have these info on the users table. Moreover if you want to change a user name you'd have to update it on each line the user has been added a favourite or blacklisted. Check my answer I added an SQL query to retrieve the info

Comment: your other option is to have a list of all blacklisted users in one column (each user being sperated by a coma or semicolon) and the same for the favourites. This keeps the numberof rows down, but I think you'll probably get better performance from the table proposed by koopajah.

Comment: @PeterScott then u think its better to have 2 left join in this case..this wont cause bad performance?

Comment: @HiDd3N I was agreeing with him only on how to structure the DB. How you retrieve the data depends on how you plan to use it. Do you only need to fetch the blocked/favourited users at specific times? Such as when sending an instant message, or whetever features your website has? If so then you wouldn't have to use a join, you could just make a seperate request when the blocked/favourited users were needed.

Comment: @PeterScott no i just want to create a page and name it blacklist.php and in this page user can find persons who blacklisted.if person is in blacklist and you go to his profile you cant see his profile and some message will echo for user.then just in one page its usefull and thats blacklist.php or favoritelist.php

Comment: @HiDd3N I'd just make a seperate query then.

Comment: @PeterScott thanks peter.if you say this strucrtre is good then i should accept this answer thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

One place to look for ready made data models is databaseanswers.com.  Here is the page that catalogs their data models.

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm

There's a section on Social Networking Sites, but it's pretty sparse.