# MySQL database table design for black lists

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have a PHP application and I need to store black list data. My site members will add any user to his/her black list. So they won't see the texts of that users.

Every user's black list is different.
A user can have 1000-1500 users in his/her black list.
User can add/remove anybody from his/her list.
Black list will have member's id and black listed people's ids.

I'm trying to design database table for this. But I couldn't be sure about how can structure be ?
I have 7-8 MySQL tables but none of them is like this.

Way 1:

```
--member ID-----black listed people (BLOB)
-----------------------------------------
--1234----------(Some BLOB data)---------
--6789----------(Some BLOB data)---------
```

I can serialize blacklisted people's IDs and save them inside a BLOB data column. When a user want to edit his/her list, I get BLOB data from table, remove unwanted ID and update column with new data. IT seems like a bit slow operation when a user has 1k-2k IDs.

Way 2:

```
--member ID----black listed ID--------
--------------------------------------
--1234---------113434545--------------
--1234---------444445454--------------
--1234---------676767676--------------
--6789---------534543545--------------
--6789---------353453454--------------
```

In this way, when a user wants to see his/her black list I give them all users in "black listed ID" column. When editing I add/remove new rows to table. This operation is fast but the table can be huge in time.

Way 3:

```
--member ID----113434545----444445454----676767676---534543545-----353453454
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--1234--------yes------------yes------------yes------------no------no-------
--6789--------no-------------no-------------no-------------yes------yes------
```

Yes shows black listed, No shows not black listed. I create new column for each black listed person and update that column when a user adds a person or removes it.

Way 4:

???

These are my ideas. I really appreciate if you can offer me a better one?
Thank you.

Comment: Way 2. Better for searching and more representative.

Comment: As Corrupt mentioned, way 2 is better design.

Comment: ditto its a no brainer

Comment: I udated my answer to advice on table structure.

Comment: Please don´t forget to upvote and accept answers that helped you, to help people with similar problems visiting that site.

Comment: If you have more then 1 type of list, perhaps Wish_List consider this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13660742/4260691

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are creating is a so-called **1 to n relation table**.

### 3rd version

The 3rd version would require to have n rows x n columns, where n is the amount of registred users. InnoDB has a [limit of 1000 columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html), **breaking your logic** as soon as 1001st. user registers. Not to mention that you don´t want to ALTER TABLE for every new user. Forget that.

### 1st version

The first solution is really slow: BLOB data won´t be really idexed, it tends to get into a second page (file on harddisk, effectively doubeling disk I/O), it has massive datasize overhead, sorting and grouping won't happen in RAM, and you have no efficient way for **backwards search** (how many people did blacklist user xy?)... as a general advise, try to avoid BLOB untill absolutely necesarry.

### 2nd version

The second solution is the way to go. MySQL is optimized for stuff like that, and a table with 2 numeric, indexed rows is **really** fast.

### Table design

I would create a table consisting of 
    blocker_id | blocked_id
and no separate primary key. Instead I would create a 2-column-primary-key with blocker beeing the first column and blocked the second. That way you save a B-Tree (expensive to create index) and can search fast for both all blockeds from a blocker (using half of the key) and for the existence of a single combination. (That will be most relevant for filtering posts, and should be optimized for.)

Comment: I just stumbled across this answer and want to point out that InnoDB has a limit of 1000 *columns*, not 1000 *rows*. You may want to correct this answer in that respect.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should make the blacklist like way 2:

```
black_list_id | blocker | blocked
```

So when you want to take whom a user blocks you would get it by `SELECT * FROM black_list_table WHERE blocker = :user_id`.

To get who is blocking the user you get `SELECT SELECT * FROM black_list_table WHERE blocked = :user_id`.

You can easily take how many people block user, how many blocked people user has, and moreover, you can set indices on all columns and get other users' data using `JOIN` statements.